# enctype='multipart/form-data' Post request fails when requested for the first time

Tags: php, http

So I need to make a form which accepts multiple photos to upload and looks something like this:

```html
<form action='' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
  <input type='text' name='title' required /><br>
  <input type='file' name='photos[]' accept='image/*' multiple required /><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Create" />
</form>
```

The problem is when I initially click the submit button using the code below to echo my input

```php
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  echo $_POST['title'];
  print_r($_FILES['photos']);
}
```

php throws a notice,

```
Notice: Undefined index: title in /var/www/html/test.php on line 7
```

but when I refresh the page or submit a different form right after submitting the previous form everything works as intended except no files are outputed.

The problem doesn't seem to occur when I select less that 10 photos.

I have tried firefox and chrome and both produce the same result.

Comment: post the PHP part

Comment: I agree with Giacomo M. As it stand there seems to be insufficient information in the question to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have made a page with the code you've given, after your edit, and my PHP code nicely returns the title and 2 photos. In other words: I still cannot reproduce your problem. Try to write out the code that will let us reproduce your problem. Keep it as short as possible, and test it before your publish it.

Comment: I did more testing and it appears the problem only happens when I select 10 or more photos.

Comment: It could be that you're going over the maximum upload size with so many photos. Have a look at [upload_max_filesize](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) and [post_max_size](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size).